# Syntax for nested queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. stocktake
2. supplier
3. accessories

I want to select `total_inventories,accessory_id,supplier_id,conpany_name,phone_no`
this 5 things in this three table
and the `total_inventories`have to <100

and I have to use  Nested Query or either standard or correlated sub-query

that is what I have done

```
SELECT total_inventories,accessory_id,supplier_id,conpany_name,phone_no
FROM stocktake,supplier,accessories
WHERE stocktake.accessory_id=accessory.accessory_id,accessory.supplier_id=supplier.supplier_id,
accessory_id IN (SELECT accessory_id FROM stocktake WHERE total_inventories <100)
```

but it got an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'accessory.supplier_id=supplier.supplier_id,
accessory_id in (select accessory_i' at line 3
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: See about sql syntax and the use of the word 'and'

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please share your full table structure with full select query so we could help more !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few things to mention in your code

> 1. you are using `accessories` table but using `accessory.supplier_id`. so you need to use correct the table name.
> 2. always use `explicit` join instead of `implicit` joins.
> 3. always use alias for the tables for more readability.
> 4. use `exists` instead of `IN`

```
FROM stocktake s

join accessories a
on s.accessory_id = a.accessory_id

join supplier su
on a.supplier_id = su.supplier_id

WHERE a.accessory_id IN (SELECT accessory_id FROM stocktake WHERE total_inventories < 100)
```

In your solution you can replace `IN` with `exists` as following

```
WHERE a.accessory_id exists 
(
  SELECT 
    accessory_id 
  FROM stocktake s 
  WHERE a.accessory_id = s.accessory_id
  and total_inventories < 100
)
```

Comment: I think if table structure is shared also we don't need the nested sub-query .... where we could  user Join where stocktake.total_inventories < 100 ;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use comma in where operator try. You can also refer join operation in sql.

```
FROM stocktake,supplier,accessories
WHERE stocktake.accessory_id=accessory.accessory_id and accessory.supplier_id=supplier.supplier_id and
accessory_id IN (SELECT accessory_id FROM stocktake WHERE total_inventories <100)
```

The query can be optimized as:

```
FROM stocktake,supplier,accessories
WHERE stocktake.accessory_id=accessory.accessory_id and accessory.supplier_id=supplier.supplier_id and
stocktake.total_inventories <100
```

We would not need subquery, we can directly filter total_inventories values as we have already joined three tables.

Comment: This isn't an answer better be a comment.